# Could developers of ios apps know the relative version of each review?

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, version, review

I want to know whether the developer could know the relative verion of each review. Because users may upload their reviews without updating their apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can see reviews filtered by app version as well as region. Login to the appstoreconnect -> under App Store tab -> Rating and Review